# Can't disconnect with nmcli

Tags: networking, wifi, nmcli

In the past this command has worked well for me, when disconnecting from a network without turning off my wifi interface:

```
nmcli con down id MyWifiName
```

When I run it now I'm getting:

```
Error: 'MyWifiName' is not an active connection.
Error: no active connection provided.
```

*I might not be connected via nmcli.*

Is there another way I can turn off the network? I need to make sure the interface stays on. Otherwise I would try something like `nmcli radio wifi off`.

Anyone know another command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up finding the source of this issue by running `nmcli c` which returned a list of all the available wifi connections.

The connection I was on was highlighted in green with the name `MyWifiName 2`. For some reason the list included duplicates of my wifi network `MyWifiName`, `MyWifiName1`, and `MyWifiName2`.

So I tried running `nmcli con down id "MyWifiName 2"` which worked.